# Get profile/permission set complete metadata independent of package.xml

Tags: metadata-api

How do I get the complete metadata of a profile or a permission set, independent of the package.xml specified in the retrieve call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. With the metadata API, if you want all the pieces of the profile metadata, you will need to request all the individual pieces and then ignore everything else to use only the profile.

Probably not the answer you were looking for but thats all is available right now.

Sridhar

Comment: I guess we need to embrace the reality. Thanks Sridhar. :)